# How to change the color of google map api draggable markers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pug

what I am trying to achieve is when ever i create a new marker it should have a different color.This is my $scope .

```
$scope.addRoute = function() {
     console.log('addRoute');
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position: {lat: 52.02, lng: 10.56},
      visible:true,
      icon:'',
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });      

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Symbol)

In your existing `$scope.addRoute` function instead of `icon:''` use `generateIcon()`.

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : {
            lat : 52.02,
            lng : 10.56
        },
        visible : true,
        icon : generateIcon(),
        map : map,
        draggable : true

    });
```

You will need to add this function in you controller.

```
function generateIcon() {
    //http://map-icons.com/ for svg path
    return {

        path : 'M0-48c-9.8 0-17.7 7.8-17.7 17.4 0 15.5 17.7 30.6 17.7 30.6s17.7-15.4 17.7-30.6c0-9.6-7.9-17.4-17.7-17.4z',
        scale : 0.5,
        fillColor : '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16),
        fillOpacity : 100,
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i add this to my exciting scope

Comment: the problem is @Searching this scope is in controllers the guys who worked on this did not use directives

Comment: @Frank , Can you try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/maxcache/4f8qzvyz/ ? This is a simple setup. It's just adding marker with random color as you wanted in the question..

Comment: working please thumbs up. one last question how to change the opacity of  the colors like i am read green bright colors

Comment: @Frrank  try the `fillOpacity` option between 0 to 100. check the docs... U might find more info on options u can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the icon with desired color:

```
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
{
  position: {lat: 52.02, lng: 10.56},
  visible:true,
  icon:'',
  map: map,
  draggable: true
}); 

marker2.setIcon('https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');

var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker(
{
  position: {lat: 62.02, lng: 12.56},
  visible:true,
  icon:'',
  map: map,
  draggable: true
}); 

marker3.setIcon('https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png')
```

Or you can change the color directly from the URL :

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FE7569
```

Comment: this solution would effect the performance of the lets say you need 100 different icons you would not rely on just adding them like this by the way for 2 markers this is the best